# "initializer element is not constant" when declaring an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is how I declare my array :

```
NSArray *atouts = [[NSArray alloc] arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",nil];
```

but I'm getting :

*Initializer element is not constant*

What would be the best way to declare a static array then ?

Answer (score 3):

You want either:

```
NSArray * atouts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
```

Or:

```
NSArray * atouts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
```

**edit** however, the real problem is that you can't initialize a static array like this.  You have to do something like:

```
static NSArray * atouts = nil;

//in some method that's invoked early
atouts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
```

Comment: hmm, still getting it using any of those 2 lines, could it be related to my header file ? ( NSArray *atouts; )

Comment: thanks for looking into it, however it's now erroring like this : "warning: data definition has no type or storage class" - "warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'atouts'" - " error: conflicting types for 'atouts'"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you get that error in that line ? Because the error is about C arrays, AFAIK.

Anyway, instead of [[NSArray alloc] arrayWithObjects:...] you need to use either [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...] or [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]. Note that the later is autoreleased.